# Plotly not working properly within R shiny App

Tags: r, plotly, shinyapps

I am trying to show a plot chart after the button is clicked, which means the chart will only show up when the button is clicked, but the chart is just not showing up... any clue with this? Here is the code:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("button", "Show Chart")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("bar")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      category <- c('task1', 'task2', 'task2','task1','task1')
      start_min <- c(0, 0, 16, 45, 40)
      stop_min <- c(14.9,18.8,17.5,65.5, 70)
      group <- c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B')
      data <- data.frame(category,start_min,stop_min,group)
      
      task_bars <- ggplot(data, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=1,
                                            xmin=start_min, xmax=stop_min,
                                            fill=as.factor(category),
                                            text=paste("Task:", str_wrap(string = category, width = 70,),
                                                       "<br>Start: ", format(start_min, digits=1), "min", 
                                                       "<br>Stop: ", format(stop_min, digits=1), "min")
      )) +
        geom_rect(alpha=0.8) +
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(
          axis.title.x=element_text(color="white"), axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) +
        scale_fill_discrete(breaks=data$category)
      
      task_bars <- plotly::ggplotly(task_bars, tooltip="text", width = 970, height = 120) %>%
        plotly::config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
        plotly::layout(plot_bgcolor='black', paper_bgcolor='black', margin = list(b=30, l=0, r=10, t=30))
      
      print(task_bars)
      output$bar <- renderPlotly(task_bars)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `output$bar` outside of the `observeEvent`. I created a reactiveValues object for your plot. The `observeEvent` creates the plot and then it will be displayed in the output.

You also had `plotOutput` in ui instead of `plotlyOutput` in ui.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

task_bars <- reactiveValues(plot = NULL)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("button", "Show Chart")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput("bar")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      category <- c('task1', 'task2', 'task2','task1','task1')
      start_min <- c(0, 0, 16, 45, 40)
      stop_min <- c(14.9,18.8,17.5,65.5, 70)
      group <- c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B')
      data <- data.frame(category,start_min,stop_min,group)
      
      task_bars$plot <- ggplot(data, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=1,
                                            xmin=start_min, xmax=stop_min,
                                            fill=as.factor(category)
      )) +
        geom_rect(alpha=0.8) +
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(
          axis.title.x=element_text(color="white"), axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) +
        scale_fill_discrete(breaks=data$category)

    })
      
    output$bar <- renderPlotly({
if(input$button == 0){
return()
} else {
      print(plotly::ggplotly(task_bars$plot, tooltip="text", width = 970, height = 120) %>%
        plotly::config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
        plotly::layout(plot_bgcolor='black', paper_bgcolor='black', margin = list(b=30, l=0, r=10, t=30))
      )
}
    })
  }
)
```